# Pass object to before_filter to perform additional logic before create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

I need perform some extra logic on an object before it is saved to the database. I would assume that using a before_filter would be the correct way to accomplish this, but I'm not sure how to pass the object to be saved into my before_filter method.

Comment: If the logic is only to be applied to that one object on save it should probably go directly in the model.  A few more details on what you're trying to do could inform the feedback.

Comment: I have a new Post object the post should belong to a member and get a thumbnail from a another function I have written, before the object is saved to the database I want to set the member ID as well as run the thumbnail function and add the url from that to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That all sounds like model code to me.  To get the most out of Rails (or any MVC framework) follow the 'Fat Models, Skinny Controllers' rule of thumb.  It can be taken too far, but I think in this case it's pretty clear.  If there are errors with the helper functions you mention, shouldn't the save action fail with appropriate error messages?

There's lots of good posts on SO on this subject.  [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467113/fat-models-skinny-controllers-and-the-mvc-design-pattern)

If this doesn't give you enough to work with I'd suggest posting some code.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first ever post here so go easy on me!

Theres a before_save method, in Rails 3 at least, that can be called in the model. 
in Posts model

```
before_save :add_url_and_ID


def add_url_and_ID
#extra logic
self[:url] = whatever.com
self[:member_id] = member.id
end
```

I'm probably way off but its my first go!