# MVC design in codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, architecture

When should a new model or controller be made? Should there only be controllers that go with a corresponding view 1 to 1 and like so with controllers and models? Or is it good practice to have controllers for functionality not tied up with any particular view? Take for example voting, should all voting code go in a voting controller or be spread among controllers that have views using voting. Seems likely a voting controller would be best.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fat models, skinny controllers and the MVC design pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467113/fat-models-skinny-controllers-and-the-mvc-design-pattern)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC in PHP: Fat Model or Fat Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568553/mvc-in-php-fat-model-or-fat-controller)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all , you cannot actually implement classical MVC in php. The best you can do is Model2 MVC.

- **Model** - responsible for all the business logic. Has no clue about *where* the data is stored or actually comes from. The storage and retrieval is responsibility of [DataMappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) or DAOs. Model itself should **never** contain SQL. Ever.
- **Controller** - binds model(s) to the view and changes the state of both. It **does not** retrieve information from models for sending it to view.
- **View** - responsible for all presentational logic. Retrieves information from models and binds it to appropriate templates. View itself **is not a template**.

You can wither have `1:1` relationship between views an controller or `many:many`. it depends on how you implement the view itself.

For example, your view can require a separate object which handles the rendering. And providing different type of objects ( this is where polymorphism matters ), you can make your view to render either xml, html or json.

Or you can do the same by changing the templates. A `ListView` class can render a list of articles as well as list of users, if the basic presentation logic does not change and you provide just a different template for each.

In the case of voting , it seems ok to have a single controller for all voting related operations, and you can have a single view with switching the templates for your output.

Comment: Good point about the view object and templates not necessarily being the same thing. In some frameworks, the view object is created by loading the relevant template so the distinction gets a bit blurred.

Comment: I do not agree with you, here is more correct MVC model: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html (and they did implement it, so it's possible).

Comment: @OZ_ , actually the link for symfony's model is [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) .. and they talk almost exclusively about ORMs. And in some examples it even looks like they have SQL fragments in controllers .. i'm kinda wary when it comes to SF and coding practices =/

Comment: @tereško maybe it was examples "what you shouldn't do"? My link is correct, I disagree with your description of controller exactly. I think only one author of code can be good enough for you. And you know who is it.

Comment: @OZ_ Yeah , i really think that Fowler is pretty good at writing code .. and you wrote `here is more correct MVC model:` and linked to the controllers. Maybe you should chack back with that wikipedia link about controllers then.

Comment: @tereško  the above is completely wrong, model always contains DB script and the controller contains the business logic always...

Comment: @dhpratik you  might not understand what exactly Teresko telling. You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000 to know and yes he is absolutely right

Answer (score 2):

Some of this sort of thing is down to preferences and opinion; there's no single correct way. Some approaches might be more flexible, but maybe at the expense of being more complex.

With regard to your example of "voting", that may depend upon how voting is going to be used in your site. Will votes appear on different types of pages? If so, some sort of component is a good approach; the voting component view can then be used to display its data within different pages, with a Voting component controller accepting the results of votes and then maybe redirecting somewhere else (or accepting votes by an Ajax request).

Very often you'll find that a models (and controllers) map more or less 1:1 to tables in a database. So if I have a table `users`, I might have a corresponding `User` model, and `UserController` controller.

Remember what a controller is intended to do: respond to a request, working out which models need to be loaded, then asking them to store, manipulate and return data which is then transferred to the view for displaying.  It's fine to have controllers that don't map directly to models. You might have a controller called `DebugController` that responds to requests to `http://examples.com/debug/`, and doesn't map directly to a `Debug` model and table, but gathers information about the system and various models (of course, there is the argument that all that stuff *should* be wrapped up into a `Debug` model, which in turn loads other models and assembles the data that the controller requests).

As for views, you will normally have more than one view for a given controller; often one view per *action*. So `UserController::indexAction()` has `views/user/index.php`, `UserController::editAction()` has `views/user/edit.php` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The approach might be flexible, that is true.

**Models** - Describe the tier that is communicating directly with database, all the SQL queries. 
    You can have model for each table in DB that will handle all actions connected to that table (select, insert, update, delete).
    You can have model for each "logical entity", modul in your application that will handle the actions for this entity. Like in your example "Voting", where you can define the logic of this modul.
    (Check if the user has allready voted, getVoteCount...)

**Controler** - Handle the request by executing functions in the model (they should not comunicate directly in DB) and passing the processed data to appropriate View. If you need to present the same data differently on different page, the controler should decide on which view to send the data.

**View** - You need view for each page, form, module in you application. It is on personal experiance how you are going to organize the views.