# Where to register event listeners

Tags: php, events, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to use the Event System in CakePHP v2.1+

It appears to be quite powerful, but the documentation is somewhat vague. Triggering the event seems pretty straight-forward, but I'm not sure how to register the corresponding listener(s) to listen for the event. The relevant section is [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners) and it offers the following example code:

```
App::uses('CakeEventListener', 'Event');
class UserStatistic implements CakeEventListener {

    public function implementedEvents() {
        return array(
            'Model.Order.afterPlace' => 'updateBuyStatistic',
        );
    }

    public function updateBuyStatistic($event) {
        // Code to update statistics
    }
}

// Attach the UserStatistic object to the Order's event manager
$statistics = new UserStatistic();
$this->Order->getEventManager()->attach($statistics);
```

But it does not say *where* this code should reside. Inside a specific controller? Inside the app controller?

In case it's relevant, the listener will be part of a plugin which I am writing.

**Update:**
It sounds like a popular way to do this is by placing the listener registration code in the plugin's bootstrap.php file. However, I can't figure out how to call getEventManager() from there because the app's controller classes, etc aren't available.

**Update 2:**
I'm also told that listeners can live inside Models.

**Update 3:**
Finally some traction! The following code will successfully log an event when inside of my MyPlugin/Config/bootstrap.php

```
App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event'); 
App::uses('CakeEventListener', 'Event');
class LegacyWsatListener implements CakeEventListener {

    public function implementedEvents() {
        return array(
            'Controller.Attempt.complete' => 'handleLegacyWsat',
        );
    }

    public static function handleLegacyWsat($event) { //method must be static if used by global EventManager
        // Code to update statistics
        error_log('event from bootstrap');
    }
}
 CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(array('LegacyWsatListener', 'handleLegacyWsat'), 'Controller.Attempt.complete');
```

I'm not sure why, but I can't get errors when I try to combine the two `App::uses()` into a single line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Events

Events are callbacks that are associated to a string. An object, like a Model will trigger an event using a string even if nothing is listening for that event.

CakePHP comes pre-built with internal events for things like Models. You can attach an event listener to a Model and respond to a `Model.beforeSave` event.

### The EventManager

Every Model in Cake has it's own EventManager, plus there is a gobal singleton EventManager. These are not all the same instance of EventManager, and they work slightly differently.

When a Model fires an event it does so using the EventManager reference it has. This means, you can attach an event listener to a specific Model. The advantages are that your listener will only receive events from that Model.

Global listeners are ones attached to the singleton instance of EventManager. Which can be accessed anywhere in your code. When you attach a listener there it's called for *every* event that happens no matter who triggers it.

When you attach event listener in the `bootstrap.php` of an app or plugin, then you can use the global manager, else you have to get a reference to the Model you need using `ClassRegistry`.

### What EventManager To Use?

If the event you want to handle is for a specific Model, then attach the listener to that Model's EventManager. To get a reference of the model you can call the `ClassRegistry::init(...)`.

If the event you want to handle could be triggered anywhere, then attach the listener to the global EventManager.

Only you know how your listener should be used.

### Inside A Listener

Generally, you put your business logic into models. You shouldn't need to access a Controller from an event listener. Model's are much easier to access and use in Cake.

Here is a template for creating a CakeEventListener. The listener is responsible for monitoring when something happens, and then passing that information along to another Model. You should place your business logic for processing the event in Models.

```
<?php

App::uses('CakeEventListener', 'Event');

class MyListener implements CakeEventListener
{
    /**
     *
     * @var Document The model.
     */
    protected $Document;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // get a reference to a Model that we'll use
        $this->Document = ClassRegistry::init('Agg.Document');
    }

    /**
     * Register the handlers.
     *
     * @see CakeEventListener::implementedEvents()
     */
    public function implementedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'Model.User.afterSave'=>'UserChanged'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Use the Event to dispatch the work to a Model.
     *
     * @param CakeEvent $event
     *          The event object and data.
     */
    public function UserChanged(CakeEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->data;
        $subject = $event->subject();

        $this->Document->SomethingImportantHappened($data,$subject);
    }
}
```

What I like to do is place all my Events into the `Lib` folder. This makes it very easy to access from anywhere in the source code. The above code would go into `App/Lib/Event/MyListener.php`.

### Attaching The EventListeners

Again, it depends on what events you need to listen for. The first thing you have to understand is that an object must be created in order to fire the event.

#### For example;

It's not possible for the `Document` model to fire `Model.beforeSave` event when the `Calendar` controller is displaying an index, because the Calendar controller never uses the `Document` model. Do you need to add a listener to `Document` in the `bootstrap.php` to catch when it saves? No, if `Document` model is only used from the `Documents` controller, then you only need to attach the listener there.

On the other hand, the `User` model is used by the `Auth` component almost every. If you want to handle a `User` being deleted. You might have to attach an event listener in the `bootstrap.php` to ensure no deletes sneak by you.

In the above example we can attach directly to the `User` model like so.

```
App::uses('MyListener','Lib');
$user = ClassRegistry::init('App.User');
$user->getEventManager()->attach(new MyListener());
```

This line will import your listener class.

```
App::uses('MyListener','Lib');
```

This line will get an instance of the User Model.

```
$user = ClassRegistry::init('App.User');
```

This line creates a listener, and attaches it to the User model.

```
$user->getEventManager()->attach(new MyListener());
```

If the `User` Model is used in many different places. You might have to do this in the `bootstrap.php`, but if it's only used by one controller. You can place that code in the `beforeFilter` or at the top of the PHP file.

#### What About Global EventManager?

Assuming we need to listen for general events. Like when ever **any** thing is saved. We would want to attach to the global EventManager. It would go something like this, and be placed in the `bootstrap.php`.

```
App::uses('MyListener','Lib');
CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(new MyListener());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to attach an event listener inside bootstrap.php file of your plugin, everything should work fine using the hints posted in the answers. Here is my code (which works properly):

MyPlugin/Config/bootstrap.php:

```
App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');
App::uses('MyEventListener', 'MyPlugin.Lib/Event');
CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(new MyEventListener());
```

MyPlugin/Lib/Event/MyEventListener.php:

```
App::uses('CakeEventListener', 'Event');
class MyEventListener implements CakeEventListener {
    ...
}
```

Event listeners related to MyPlugin are being registered only when the plugin is loaded. If I don't want to use the plugin, event listeners are not attached. I think this is a clean solution when you want to add some functionality in various places in your app using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Its' not important, where the code resides. Just make sure its being executed and your events are properly registered & attached.

We're using a single file where all events are attached and include it from bootstrap.php, this ensures that all events are available from all locations in the app.

The magic happens when you dispatch an event, like from an controller action.

```
$event = new CakeEvent('Model.Order.afterPlace', $this, array('some'=>'data') ));
$this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);
```

However, you can dispatch events from anywhere you can reach the EventManager (in Models, Controller and Views by default)

Comment: I guess at the heart of my problem is the fact that I can't seem to access the EventManager from inside bootstrap.php. Can you help me do that? I've tried to call the getEventManager() method statically but I can't get it to work.

Comment: just "use" 
`App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');`
`CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(array('UserStatistic', 'updateBuyStatistic'), 'Model.Order.afterPlace');`. I guess, you'll also need to "use" the approriate class, where the event is going to be handled.

Comment: When I do this I get: `Class 'CakeEventManager' not found`

Comment: Nothing seems to be available inside my plugin's bootstrap.php file. I keep getting recommendations to do this, but none of them actually work as they're written. I can't tell if there's something screwed up about my plugin or if people are giving me code meant to go somewhere else.

Comment: You used `App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');` and still get "class not found"? That sounds odd, you should be able to use cakes internal library from anywhere. Just to be sure, forget the plugin for now and try implement it straight in the app, just to make it working for once ;)

Comment: Can you give me a specific code snippet that should work in a specific  file. I'm still trying to figure out how the Event Manager works, and I'm still not clear which syntax should work where.