# CakePHP - Set viewVar from within EventListener

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following event listener but want to set a viewVar from it and having some issues figuring out how. If I can't or shouldn't, what would be the best way when I need `$products` available to the View?

File is `./Products/Lib/Event/Products.php`.

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeEventListener', 'Event');

class Products implements CakeEventListener {
    public function implementedEvents() {
        return array(
            'View.beforeRender' => 'get_products',
        );
    }

    public function get_products($event) {
        $this->Product = ClassRegistry::init('Products.Product');

        $products = $this->Product->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('Product.*', 'Content.title')
        ));

        $this->set('products', $products);
    }
}
```

Returns `Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Products::set()`.

Comment: Haven't used cake in close to a decade, but, does the class Products have a `set` function?  Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Speaking in general terms you need to pass the View/App in or be able to pull it out of the Registry to be able to access it there. These guys like statics... There an `App::get`?  Searching and these were most useful I could find. http://martinbean.co.uk/blog/2013/11/22/getting-to-grips-with-cakephps-events-system/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923246/where-to-register-event-listeners  Good luck!

Comment: How about moving this logic to the AppController? This could make `$products` available everywhere.

Comment: @Mary The AppController is part of the core which is shared across multiple projects, so on this specific project I need `$products` available to all views and went with the event listener method, until I hit that I couldn't figure out how to get it to the views.

Comment: Since when is `AppController` part of the core? That should definitely only exist in your application.

Comment: @ndm I meant the AppController is in a shared repo for our projects. It's a CMS framework where the main Cake App with shared plugins is in a shared repo and each site just clones it and has it's own theme and own plugins. So, I couldn't add this to the AppController or it would be there for every project vs just this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are subscribing to an event triggered by a `View` object, hence the subject of the event will be that object, and you can access it in your listener method via the event objects `subject()` method, like:

```
$event->subject()->set('products', $products);
```

See also

- **[API > CakeEvent::subject()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-CakeEvent.html#_subject)**
- **[API > View::render()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-View.html#_render)**
- **[API > View::set()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-View.html#_set)**

Comment: Huge thanks for this and the doc links! It's working and I understand what I needed to do more.